# Cannot import parent component class into child component Angular

Tags: angular

I have one component named nagivation.component. I have exported that component to use as Parent component. Then I have imported it in an child component. But where I am getting following error 
[image]

Here is the code of child component for your reference

```
 import { NagivationComponent } from './nagivation/nagivation.component';
```

Here is the screenshot of app.module.ts
[image]

Comment: Did you made a module from your component?

Comment: I think you have not imported the parent component in the module.ts file. Try to import there I think it will work.

Comment: Are you sure about the file address? It might cause this problem

Comment: @Rounak Snehasis   Please see the updated question. I imported the parent component in aap.module.ts

Comment: Yes file address also right.

Comment: @Mohahammad Kermani - you are right. There was a problem in file path. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I think the address in the component file should be '../nagivation/nagivation.component' instead of './nagivation/nagivation.component' because in module.ts its './nagivation/nagivation.component'. It should be one folder up if called inside one component.

Comment: Yes @Rounak Snehasis you are right. Thanks